# Converting Roman Numeral to Arabic numbers

Tags: c++, string, switch-statement

So i have one my functions working but the functions to check if the string inputted by the user only contains roman numerals ( M,D,V,X,C,L,I) and to convert the roman numerals to arabic numbers ( 1,2,3,4, etc.) arent working. Can anyone help ?? I need it formatted in C++.

I have tested the romanValue function and it works great, but i need to edit the convertRomantoArabic function to take the input string, check it with the romanValue function and sum of the values of the roman numerals and display the total value to the screen.

this is my whole program:

```
   #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    #include <cassert>
    #include <cstddef>

    using namespace std;

    //This function searches in the string to see if the string only contains 
    //Roman Numeral values
    //Pre:none
    //Post:none
    string isRoman(string roman){
            for(const auto& c:roman){
                if(!(c == 'M' || c == 'D' || c == 'C' || 
                c == 'L' || c == 'X' || c == 'V' || c == 'I')){
                    cout<<"Not Roman";
                }
                cout<<"Is Roman";
            }
   }

     //This Function finds the Roman Numeral and returns the value
    //Pre: none
    //Post: none
    int romanValue(char roman){
            switch(roman){
                case'M':
                    return 1000;
                case'D':
                    return 500;
                case'C':
                    return 100;
                case'L':
                    return 50;
                case 'X':
                    return 10;
                case'V':
                    return 5;
                 case'I':
                    return 1;
                default:
                    cout<<"Not a Roman Value: "<<roman<<endl;
                    return 0;
            }
}

//This Function Takes the Roman Numerals entered, finds their value, Adds up 
//Adds up their value and then converts them to Arabic numbers.
//Pre: none
//Post: None
int convertRomantoArabic(string arabic){
            int i,ans =0, p=0;
            int n = arabic.length()-1;

            for(i = n; i > 0;i--){
               if(romanValue(arabic[i] >= p)){
                   ans = ans + romanValue(arabic[i]);
               }
                  ans = ans - romanValue(arabic[i]); 

                  p = romanValue(arabic[i]);
            }
            return ans;
        }
int main()
{
    string romanLet;
    int getRomanValue; 
    cout<<"Please enter a Roman Numeral: ";
    cin>>romanLet;

    string findRoman = isRoman(romanLet);

    cout<<findRoman; 

    //getRomanValue = convertRomantoArabic(romanLet);

    //cout<<getRomanValue;
            return 0;
}
```

Comment: 1) Did you try stepping through your code with a debugger, to figure out why it doesn't work, as you intended? 2) [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius i went through it step by step, like my instructor has taught me, and i cant figure out how to edit the first and last function for them to properly function

Comment: First, one must figure out what, exactly, isn't working (that's where using the debugger comes in), and only then, one can fix the issue. You cannot fix something, when you don't know what is wrong in the first place.

Comment: Perhaps `isRoman` should call `romanValue` for each character? That avoids duplicating information

Comment: Please include (1) test values (2) expected results (3) actual results

Comment: If you aren't testing this one, please do:`IV`. Expected result: `4`. Incorrect result: `6`

Comment: @TimRandall how should i format isRoman so that it checks if the string inputed has the valid Roman Numeral because essentially if it only contains roman numerals, it will exit that function and proceed to the convertRomantoArabic function which calls romanValue

Comment: Honestly, `isRoman` should return a `bool` which is true if the input is a valid roman numeral and false otherwise. Returning a string is just making your life more complicated, in my opinion

Comment: @TimRandall when i input a value, it just returns a blank line and ends the program

Comment: @TimRandall well that is my intention but i need to check if it has valid roman numerals, if yes, it will return true, but my problem is the if statement to check for the roman numerals

Comment: You have declared `isRoman` as a function that returns a string, but you do not have a `return` statement in the function definition. I am surprised that your compiler isn't warning you about this. My compiler will refuse to compile this code.

Answer (score 0):

Your logic as written is not sufficient to correctly decode a Roman numeral.  As previously noted, `IV` is 4, not 6.

And, a ten-second Google search *will* lead you directly to several code examples which do work. *(So, if this isn't homework, "do not do a thing already done.™")*

If you want to work out the algorithm for yourself, let me give you this hint:  *"run the string **backwards**,"* remembering the numeric value of the previous character that you saw.  "If you encounter an `I` having previously encountered a `V` when working backwards, you know to ..."

Comment: i have found multiple but we just learned arrays, so i can't use anything past arrays in my program , so could you assist with a coded example?

Comment: So this *is* homework!  Let me therefore **strongly** encourage you to work with your instructor.  Not only can s/he help you, but s/he will thereby know what ought to be discussed in the next classroom session.  *(I'm an adjunct professor at a local community college, so I speak from the heart – "remember, we can't read minds.")